# TikZ: Draw angle with label between lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, technical-drawing

How do I draw an angle **with a label** between two lines when the lines are not necessarily drawn in the same `\draw` call?

*I need to draw an angle with a label, theta, between the y-axis and the pendulum string (see picture below).*

*Other suggestions/improvements of my code/diagram are welcome.*

**Current code:**

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (origo) at (0,0);
\coordinate (pivot) at (1,5);

% draw axes
\fill[black] (origo) circle (0.05);
\draw[thick,gray,->] (origo) -- ++(4,0) node[black,right] {$x$};
\draw[thick,gray,->] (origo) -- ++(0,-4) node[black,below] {$y$};

% draw roof
\fill[pattern = north east lines] ($ (origo) + (-1,0) $) rectangle ($ (origo) + (1,0.5) $);
\draw[thick] ($ (origo) + (-1,0) $) -- ($ (origo) + (1,0) $);

\draw[thick] (origo) -- ++(300:3) coordinate (bob);
\fill (bob) circle (0.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Current output:**

[image]

For illustration, I want something like this in my diagram:

[image]

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use the `angles` library which defines a `pic` for this purpose. The `quotes` library is used for ease of labelling.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,angles,quotes}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (origo) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (pivot) at (1,5);

    % draw axes
    \fill[black] (origo) circle (0.05);
    \draw[thick,gray,->] (origo) -- ++(4,0) node[black,right] {$x$};
    \draw[thick,gray,->] (origo) -- ++(0,-4) node (mary) [black,below] {$y$};

    % draw roof
    \fill[pattern = north east lines] ($ (origo) + (-1,0) $) rectangle ($ (origo) + (1,0.5) $);
    \draw[thick] ($ (origo) + (-1,0) $) -- ($ (origo) + (1,0) $);

    \draw[thick] (origo) -- ++(300:3) coordinate (bob);
    \fill (bob) circle (0.2);

    \pic [draw, ->, "$\theta$", angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle = mary--origo--bob};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: marked angle]

If you want the angle in red with two-way arrows, just modify the last line:

```
\pic [draw=red, <->, "$\theta$", angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle = mary--origo--bob};
```

[image: modified marked angle]

## EDIT (Respond to query in comments)

To change the colour of the label as well, just set the `text` key:

```
\pic [draw=red, text=blue, <->, "$\theta$", angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle = mary--origo--bob};
```

[image: modified modified marked angle]

Comment: May I ask why you called the node `mary`? :-)

Comment: @teelf Why did you call the other one `bob`? I don't really know, is the answer. For some reason 'Bob' -> 'Other name?' got me 'Mary'. Why?

Comment: @teelf Didn't you ask how to change the colour of the marker? It seems to have disappeared but, just in case, see edit above ;).

Comment: Ha, It's a bob in a pendulum.

Comment: @teelf That makes sense ;). I wondered about that as I answered your question - but the node was already `mary` by then, I'm afraid. If you'd called it `weight`, I'd have picked something less anthropomorphic!

Comment: @cfr Is there a way to finely customize the position of the label? Using `above`, `right`, etc. works, but e.g. `above=5` doesn't increase the distance.

Comment: @Casimir The label of what? Those keys aren't used for labelling the angle, so I'm not sure what you are trying to do. In general, see the `positioning` library which allows things like `above=<dimension> of <location>` etc.

Comment: @cfr I meant the position of the angle label, i.e. `theta` in your example.

Comment: @Casimir Try changing `angle eccentricity`.

Comment: I tried out your solution and it works great. For other users i have two tips: 1. If you use `angle=(0,0)--(1,0)--(0,-1)` with points and not coordinates your latex code will throw an error. You need to add a coordinate for each point of your angle. 2. If you wish to fill the angle with a certain color you can use the `fill` option in the same style as in `\draw`.

Comment: I would like to add one more note: Unlike with notation for lines eg `\draw (mary) -- (bob);` I must not have spaces between the coordinate names. So `\pic [draw] {angle = mary -- origo -- bob};` did not work for me, but only `\pic [draw] {angle = mary--origo--bob};` did.

Answer (score 4):

Just for comparison, here's a version in plain [Metapost](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107489/what-is-metapost-metafont-and-how-can-i-get-started-using-it) with some explanatory comments.

[image: a swinging pendulum]

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

beginfig(1);

% first define the unit to use
u = 1cm;

% now define the paths and points
% next define the axes, the bob position, and the path of the pendulum
path xx, yy, pendulum; pair bob;
xx = (left -- 3 right) scaled u;
yy = (origin -- 4 down) scaled u;

theta = 24;
bob = 3 down scaled u rotated theta;
pendulum = origin -- bob;

% also define an angle mark, rotated to start on the yy axis and go as far as the pendulum
% this assumes theta is positive by the way
path angle_mark; angle_mark = fullcircle rotated 270 scaled 3/2u cutafter pendulum;

% now we can get on with drawing

% first do the striped fill for the roof area
path roof_area; roof_area = unitsquare shifted 1/2 left xscaled 2u yscaled 1/2u;
picture roof_fill;   
roof_fill = image(for x=-2u step 1/8u until 2u: draw (left--right) scaled 2u rotated 45 shifted (x,0); endfor);
clip roof_fill to roof_area;
draw roof_fill;

% now draw the axes in grey
drawarrow xx withcolor .5 white; label.rt (btex $x$ etex, point 1 of xx);
drawarrow yy withcolor .5 white; label.bot(btex $y$ etex, point 1 of yy);
% and the bottom of the roof area in black
draw subpath(0,1) of roof_area;
% draw the pendulum, the pivot at the origin, and the bob on the end of the pendulum
draw pendulum;
fill fullcircle scaled dotlabeldiam;
fill fullcircle scaled 1/3u shifted bob;

% now the angle mark - note it will lie on top of the axis and the pendulum
% if this bothers you, draw it first
ahlength := 2.5; 
drawarrow angle_mark withcolor .54 red;

% finally do the label, attached to the angle_mark
label(btex $\theta$ etex, point 1/2 of angle_mark + (1,-6)) withcolor .67 blue;

% and some optional go-faster stripes for the bob
for i=2 step 2 until 10:
  draw quartercircle scaled 1/3u rotated (135+theta-i) shifted (bob rotated -i) withcolor (i/10)*white;
endfor
endfig;
end.
```