# Drawing a diagram in latex.

Tags: diagrams

I am trying to draw a ripple pendulum similar to the below diagram but have absolutely no idea how to start, or even if it can be done in LaTeX? Another complication is I need it to have a purple background

> backgroundcolor=blue!20

Here is the diagram I am trying to draw. Thank you for any help or guidance :) 
[image]

Comment: Without any source code we can use for testing we cannot help.

Comment: Why don't you ask the author of this pic for the code? It looks like TeX to me.

Comment: Ah okay, I am completely new to drawing so was looking for any advice really i.e what package to use etc? I am a bit lost looking at the different ones and thought someone with experience would know which to use! :)

Comment: It is possible. You can try to use TikZ To draw it. But should not expect someone to do it for you if you don't give a try.

Comment: You can start with: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219038/tikz-draw-angle-with-label-between-lines

Comment: blue!20 will give some  pale blue background, not a purple one.

Comment: @Bernard or is it [white and gold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_dress_(viral_phenomenon))?

Comment: Good luck with the dynamic equations. ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One LaTeX-friendly tool for doing this type of drawing is [MetaPost](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107489/what-is-metapost-metafont-and-how-can-i-get-started-using-it). Getting started details are in the linked answer.

One technique for filling the background of an image, is to save the whole drawing in a `picture` variable, and then fill the `bbox` of the picture with the background colour, and then draw the picture on top.

Here's an example using a version of the OP image.

[image]

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

beginfig(1);

u = 1.4cm;

numeric theta[];
theta1 = 12;
theta2 = 24;
theta3 = 36;

path segment[];
segment1 = (origin -- down) scaled 1.2u rotated theta1;
segment2 = (origin -- down) scaled 1.2u rotated theta2 shifted point 1 of segment1;
segment3 = (origin -- down) scaled 1.2u rotated theta3 shifted point 1 of segment2;

picture pendulum;
pendulum = image(
    draw (left--right) scaled 2u;
    for i=1 upto 3:
      draw segment[i];
      draw (origin--down) scaled 1u
                          shifted point 0 of segment[i] 
                          dashed withdots scaled 1/3;
      label.urt(btex $\ell$ etex, point 1/2 of segment[i]);
      label.urt(btex $m$    etex, point   1 of segment[i]);
      draw subpath(0, 1/45 (theta[i]-8)) of fullcircle 
           rotated 274 scaled .6u shifted point 0 of segment[i]
           withpen pencircle scaled .3;  
    endfor
    for i=1 upto 3:
      fill fullcircle scaled 4 shifted point 1 of segment[i] withcolor .87 blue;
    endfor
    label(btex $\theta_1$ etex scaled 0.8, point 0 of segment1 shifted (-6,-12));
    label(btex $\theta_2$ etex scaled 0.8, point 0 of segment2 shifted ( 6,-25));
    label(btex $\theta_3$ etex scaled 0.8, point 0 of segment3 shifted ( 8,-20));
);

bboxmargin := 10;
fill bbox pendulum withcolor .2[white,blue];
draw pendulum;

endfig;
end.
```

Comment: A more friendly version of MetaPost-like drawing is [asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net) (C-like syntax, OOP; handles LaTeX labels (even random math) cleanly).

Comment: @vonbrand, ha ha!  those are the reasons I **don't** like Asymptote... but let's not start another my tool is better than your tool discussion.  Why not provide an Asy version of the OP diagram as another answer?

Answer (score 6):

This a `TiKZ` solution

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,angles,quotes}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%
angle eccentricity=1.2,
ball/.style={circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=2mm, fill=blue, draw=blue, label=right:$m$},
background rectangle/.style={fill=purple!20},
show background rectangle]

\draw[thick] (-2,0) --(2,0);
\draw (0,0) coordinate (b0) foreach \i [count=\ni] in {-70,-55,-30} {--++(\i:2cm) node[midway,auto]{$l$} node[ball] (b\ni) {}};

\foreach \i [count=\auxi] in {b0,b1,b2}{
    \draw[dashed] (\i)--++(-90:1.8cm) coordinate[pos=.75] (aux\auxi);
} 

\draw pic["$\theta_1$", draw, angle radius=1.2cm] {angle=aux1--b0--b1};
\draw pic["$\theta_2$",draw, angle radius=1.2cm] {angle=aux2--b1--b2};
\draw pic["$\theta_3$",draw, angle radius=1.2cm] {angle=aux3--b2--b3};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here is a `pstricks` solution:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[x11names]{pstricks}%
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}
    \psset{unit = 1.25, dotsize=5pt, dash=2pt 1.5pt, shortput=nab, linewidth=1pt}
    \psline(-2.5,0)(3,0)%
    \pnodes(0,0){O}(1.5;-70){P1}(1.5;-55){Q2}(1.5;-35){Q3}
    \uput [20](P1){$m$}
    \AplusB(P1)(Q2){P2}\uput [20](P2){$m$}
    \AplusB(P2)(1.5; -35){P3}\uput [20](P3){$m$}
    \psset{labelsep=2pt, linecolor=LightSteelBlue3}
    \ncline{O}{P1}^{$\ell$}
    \ncline{P1}{P2}^{$\ell$}
    \ncline{P2}{P3}^{$\ell$}
    \psset{linewidth=0.4pt, linecolor=black}
    \psarc(O){0.5}{-90}{-70}\uput[l](0,-0.5){$\theta_1$}
    \psarc(P1){0.5}{-90}{-55}\uput{0.55}[-70](P1){$\theta_2$}
    \psarc(P2){0.5}{-90}{-35}\uput{0.55}[-60](P2){$\theta_3$}
    \psset{linestyle=dashed}
    \psline(O)(0,-1.3)
    \psrline(P1)(0,-1.1)
    \psrline(P2)(0,-0.8)
    \psdots[linecolor=RoyalBlue4](P1)(P2)(P3)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Because of the color choice. I always like your colors :)