# simple pendulum in latex with same format as the picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

How can I draw this picture in tikz? I dont need exactly as the picture but a diagram which have these meaning. I started with this code by myself but not able to complete further

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw (0,0) rectangle (6,4);
 \draw (3,4) circle [x radius=0.1, y radius=0.1];
 \node at (3,2){y};
```

[image]

Comment: http://texample.net/tikz/examples/physical-pendulum/, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305028/graph-of-pendulum, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/262106/1952,

Comment: Thanks for the link but I am getting an error with undefined control sequence \pic \

Comment: I have tested all three links proposed by @Ignasi (at least the tikz answers), and the code compiles in all three cases on TeXLive 2016. If you have problems, please show the code and the error message.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can draw the picture you've posted easily. Simple approach is shown below and its output is

[image]

```
\documentclass[border={10pt}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,>=latex,->]

\begin{scope}
\clip(-5,2) rectangle (5,-5);

\draw[dashed] (0,0)  circle (4.24cm);
\filldraw[white] (-4.3,4.3) rectangle (4.3,0);
\draw[double distance=1.6mm] (0,0) -- (3,-3) node[midway,xshift=4mm,yshift=2mm]{$\ell$};
\draw[->] (3,-3) -- (3,-4.5) node[below]{$m\cdot g$};
\draw[->] (3,-3) -- (2.,-2.0) node[left,yshift=-3mm]{$F$};
\draw[fill=white] (-1.2,1.0) -- (-.5,0) arc(180:360:0.5) -- (1.2,1.0) -- cycle;
\draw[draw=black,fill=white] (0, 0) circle circle (.3cm);
\draw[draw=black,fill=white] (3,-3) circle circle (.3cm);
\draw[->] (.6,0) -- (2,0) node[below]{\texttt{x}};
\draw[->] (0,-.6) -- (0,-2) node[below]{\texttt{y}};
\draw[pattern=north east lines] (-1.4,1.3) rectangle (1.4,1);
\node at (.3,-.8) {$\varphi$};   
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: double `circle`?

Comment: @ferahfeza, why you don't state your concern rather than playing puzzles?

Comment: wowowowowowowowo!!! stunning

Comment: @CroCo : mathmode for *x*, *y* ?

Comment: @AlexG, true but I've tried to draw what is in the picture. Personally, I will utilize math mode rather than `texttt`.

Comment: @CroCo, I'm new in TiKz. I thought this might be a new using of `circle` or a new option.