# How to draw this figure (Dispersive prism)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw, tikz-graphdrawing

[image]

Using TikZ how can I draw this figure ?

Sorry, this time I didn't even tried to write a code, I'm really sorry :(, I know this is against the website's rules, but I really found it hard to draw.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit :**
Here's my attempt, I found it hard to draw that line through I and I', they are the midpoints of the triangle's edges.

I tried to fix it with `\begin{scope}` but it wasn't helpful :

Here's the code :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, shapes, positioning, calc, decorations.text, angles, quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[smooth, dashed] (4,2.5)--(8,5.2);
\draw[smooth, dashed] (6.1,2.3)--(4.4,4);
\draw[smooth, black] (3,0)--(5,5)--(7,0)--(3,0);
\coordinate(O) at (5,5);
\coordinate(A) at (3,0);
\coordinate(B) at (7,0);
\pic[ draw,inner sep=1pt, circle,  draw,angle eccentricity=1.1, angle radius = 10mm] {angle = A--O--B};
\node[below] at (5,4.68) {$A$}; 
\draw[thick, gray] (1,0.45)--(4,2.5)--(6.1,2.3)--(8,0.1); 

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it the Snell's law? However you can draw himself using a tool online.

Comment: You may find an interesting starting point at: https://texample.net/tikz/examples/raindrop/

Comment: you can start by drawing the prism (it's a triangle) : `\draw (a,b) --(c,d)`
The light rays correspond to segments that you can draw with `\draw (a,b) -- (c,d)` and `\draw [dashed]`
To name the angles, you will need to draw arcs of a circle : `\draw (a,b) arc (u,v,r)`
Look at the TikZ manual

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an adapted old drawing of mine. With a few changes you can have yours.

Instead of my macros for the angles, you can use angles+quotes tikz libraries (see this post: [TikZ: Draw angle with label between lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219038/tikz-draw-angle-with-label-between-lines)).

My code:

```
\documentclass [border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage    {tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\newcommand{\cangle}[6] % A,B,C,radius,style,label (circle angle at point B)
{%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\p{0.2+#4} % label position
  \begin{scope}
    \clip #1 -- #2 -- #3 -- cycle;
    \coordinate (AUX1) at ($#2!\p cm!#1$);
    \coordinate (AUX2) at ($#2!\p cm!#3$);
    \node[#5] at ($(AUX1)!0.5!(AUX2)$) {#6};
    \draw[#5] #2 circle (#4);
  \end{scope}
}

\newcommand{\sangle}[5] % A,B,C,distance,style (square angle at point B)
{%
  \coordinate (AUX1) at ($#2!#4 cm!#1$);
  \coordinate (AUX3) at ($#2!#4 cm!#3$);
  \coordinate (AUX2) at ($(AUX1)+(AUX3)-#2$);
  \draw[#5]   (AUX1) -- (AUX2) -- (AUX3);
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,line cap=round,line join=round]
  % styles
  \tikzstyle{ray}   =[red,thick,
                      decoration={markings,
                      mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow[>=stealth]{>}}},
                      postaction={decorate}]
  \tikzstyle{normal}=[blue,thin]
  % coordinates
  \coordinate (A)  at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B)  at (4,0);
  \coordinate (C)  at (60:4);
  \coordinate (I1) at (-1,1);
  \coordinate (I4) at (5,3);
  \coordinate (I2) at (intersection of A--C and I1--I4);
  \coordinate (I3) at (intersection of B--C and I1--I4);
  \coordinate (R1) at (2,2.5);
  \coordinate (R3) at (5,0);
  \coordinate (R2) at (intersection of B--C and R1--R3);
  \coordinate (N1) at ($(I2)+(150:1)$);
  \coordinate (N2) at ($(I2)+(330:2)$);
  \coordinate (N3) at ($(R2)+(30:1)$);
  \coordinate (N4) at ($(R2)+(210:2)$);
  \coordinate (N5) at (intersection of N1--N2 and N3--N4);
  \coordinate (IR) at (intersection of I1--I4 and R1--R3);
  % prism
  \draw[thick, fill=blue!5] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
  % rays
  \draw[ray]    (I1) -- (I2);
  \draw[ray]    (I2) -- (R2);
  \draw[ray]    (R2) -- (R3);
  \draw[dashed] (I2) -- (I4);
  \draw[dashed] (R1) -- (R2);
  % normal lines
  \draw[normal] (N2) -- (N1) node [left]  {$N_1$};
  \draw[normal] (N4) -- (N3) node [right] {$N_2$};
  % angles  
  \sangle{(N1)}{(I2)}{(C)} {0.1}{normal};
  \sangle{(N3)}{(R2)}{(C)} {0.1}{normal};
  \cangle{(A)} {(C)} {(B)} {0.3}{}    {$\hat\alpha$};
  \cangle{(N1)}{(N5)}{(N4)}{0.3}{blue}{$\hat\alpha$};
  \cangle{(N1)}{(I2)}{(I1)}{0.3}{red} {$\hat i_1$};
  \cangle{(N2)}{(I2)}{(R2)}{0.3}{red} {$\hat r_1$};
  \cangle{(I2)}{(R2)}{(N4)}{0.3}{red} {$\hat i_2$};
  \cangle{(R3)}{(R2)}{(N3)}{0.3}{red} {$\hat r_2$};
  \cangle{(I4)}{(I2)}{(R2)}{0.4}{}    {$\hat\beta$};
  \cangle{(R1)}{(R2)}{(I2)}{0.4}{}    {$\hat\gamma$};
  \cangle{(I1)}{(IR)}{(R1)}{0.3}{}    {$\hat\delta$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And, the prism:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, vey interesting code ! I appreciate your help.