# How to draw simple angles like this?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I draw something like this [image]

Comment: Have you looked at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219038/tikz-draw-angle-with-label-between-lines ? What is your current approach, your code? This is a very basic question that already has answers on here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A PSTricks solution just for either fun or comparison purpose.

This answer was prepared several years ago.

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(7,5)
    \pstGeonode[PointName=none,PointSymbol=none](1,4){A}(3,1){B}(6,1){C}
    \psline{<->}(A)(B)(C)
    \pstMarkAngle[MarkAngleRadius=1,LabelSep=.5]{C}{B}{A}{$120^\circ$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Note To Scale*

Comment: What is "The Shortest Mustache Theorem" ?

Comment: @hola: You can ask about this theorem and its story at [this](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 5):

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,
    quotes}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \coordinate (O);
        \draw[red,->]   (O) -- (4,0)  coordinate[label=below:${x}$]  (x);
        \draw[blue,->]  (O) -- (-4,2)  coordinate[label=above:${y}$] (q);
        %
        \pic [draw, thick, <->,
        angle radius=16mm,angle eccentricity=1.1,"$\theta$"]     {angle = x--O--q};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, it helps